# Hosting a local server through through Node.js not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm in the middle of a project which is being built through Three.js, and for the moment I am using Node.js to host a local server to run the code on. This was working well up until recently, when it for some reason stopped functioning.

I have been using Firefox when opening the local web server and I open it through "localhost:8080" after hosting a local server with Node.js. All of a sudden Firefox shows me a white screen and the server just gets stuck on loading. I decided to give Chrome a go, and see if there's an issue with Firefox. Chrome loads the server straight away and it looks to be running alright.

Except once I change something in the code, the server does not follow. Even after restarting the server, it still shows the project with the old code. No matter what I do, it loads the exact same thing.

I've double checked the location where I am hosting the server with the code that I am changing, I've made sure my antivirus is not interfering for some reason, and I've tried simply restarting the computer. I don't really understand why it stopped functioning all of a sudden after being completely fine for days.

Any ideas?

Edit: Chrome is now acting exactly like Firefox, it gets stuck loading with a white screen showing nothing.

Comment: maybe u should check into "cache" and flushing cache in order to force reload of revised code.  see devtools http cache under chrome browser

Comment: What server are you running? There are tons of node.js server libraries, the solution would vary based on which one you're using.